# MYSQL: Most sufficient way to to update only fields that are not empty?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Let's say I have this table:

```
ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
1  |  val |      |  val |
```

Is  there a way to modify this query:

```
UPDATE table set col1 = "bla", col2 = "bla", col3 = "bla", col4 = "bla where id = 1
```

So that I end up with:

```
ID | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4
1  |  val |  bla |  val |  bla
```

In other words, the query must only update the fields that are not null. How do you do that?

Comment: The question is about updating not null fields, but the examples you give is about updating null fields only, I tried to edit it but it says the edit queue is full, I think this is the reason your question is downvoted.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the simpliest answer is to use `COALESCE`

```
UPDATE table 
set     col1 = COALESCE(col1,"bla"), 
        col2 = COALESCE(col2,"bla"), 
        col3 = COALESCE(col3,"bla"), 
        col4 = COALESCE(col4,"bla")
where   id = 1
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15562/1)

Other links.

- [MySQL COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Comment: Will this still work even if the value must be '' (empty) and not necessarily null?

Comment: no, coalesce only works for null values, if you have emty columns try this, `UPDATE table 
set     col1 = CASE WHEN col1 IS NULL OR CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(col1)) = 0 THEN 'bla' ELSE col1 END,...`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of Coalesce, you could also have used IsNUll, coalesce and isnull are equivalent in many respects

```
Update Table
set col1 = Isnull(col1,'bla'),...
```

Of course If RD wants it to work for empty strings too, JW's already given a solution